# Cargo Tomcat 7.X not stopping

Tags: tomcat7, cargo

Here is my configuration in gradle file for cargo.

```
 cargo {
   containerId = 'tomcat7x'
   port = httpPort.toInteger()

   local {
   homeDir = file(cargoHome)
   configHomeDir = file(cargoHome)
   jvmArgs = 'Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9092 
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -'

installer {
  installUrl = 'https://installdirectory/content/groups/public/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat/7.0.57/tomcat-7.0.57.zip'
  downloadDir = file("$buildDir/download")
  extractDir = file("$buildDir/extract")
}
containerProperties { property 'cargo.tomcat.ajp.port', portFinder.nextAvailable}
extraClasspath = files("../service/service-1.0.0-LOCAL-local.jar",configurations.cargoruntime)  }}
```

Following error it's shows in log while running cargoStopLocal task

WARNING: StandardServer.await: Invalid command '' received
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9092; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
Nov 20, 2015 4:32:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
WARNING: StandardServer.await: Invalid command '' received

can anyone guide me how to handle this issue , it's not stopping cargo server so my build is failing?

Comment: Here is the answer I found.. https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-cargo-plugin/issues/118